# Close a Window in MSCRM 2013 by Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm

MY Test case is like on click of one Button(Update Customer) a new Window will open,after opening user verifies Data and will CLose the Window. The control need to back to Previous Window

I Have Written driver.close() . but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is that the `WebDriver` is not focusing on the previous window.

Save your previous window handle:

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

You can do this after you close the window:

```
driver.SwitchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
```

**Update**

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

// click operation that opens new window

// Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

// Do stuff

driver.close(); // This will close the current window (new one)

// Switch back to first window
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);
```

Comment: @ Jamie Rees : i Have added the line which u answered but that line throwing Below compilation error

WindowHandles cannot be resolved or is not a field

i changed WindowHandles to Windowhandles but it is giving me same error

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Jamir Rees  : Thankas Jamie.. now it's working Window is switching to previous one but the New Window Didn't Closed..That New Window is still Open

Comment: If you want to close the window you need to do `driver.close()` and then the `SwitchTo`

Comment: It is closing the Old WIndow with driver.close(); 
New Window is still open

Comment: @ Jamie Rees  : THanks Jamie.. you ROck... now i am able to close all windows Properly. Can you check Below Link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678742/doing-selenium-automation-on-lookup-field-of-mscrm-2013